# What's the plural of Rally, as in the car competition?

Tags: plural-forms

For the car race typically known as «rally», how does one form the plural?

Is it «rallies» or «rallys»?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general rule of thumb is that if a word ends in *y* and the letter immediately preceding it is a consonant, change that *y* to an *i* and add an *es*:

> rall**y** ---> rall**ies**
>
> bab**y** ---> bab**ies**
>
> cand**y** ---> cand**ies**

If it's a vowel that comes before the *y*, leave the word alone and just add an *s* to the end of it:

> pla**y** ---> play**s**
>
> ke**y** ----> key**s**
>
> wa**y** ---> way**s**

A small piece of advice. If, for some reason, you still find this rule difficult to remember, I'd recommend the following: when in doubt, just look up the word you have a problem with in a dictionary! Dictionaries usually, along with the singular forms of words, also list their plurals.

Comment: I won't speak for every dictionary, but many dictionaries only list plural form when the word doesn't follow standard pluralization rules (see, e.g., entries for [*shirt*](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=shirt) and [*goose*](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=goose) in AH).

Comment: Michael, thanks for the info. I checked the dictionary first. I thought however, that maybe because the word might had gathered a very particular sense, as in car competition, the plural would be different from what was written in the dictionary for rally as gathering of people in a broader sense...

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. Then it would be a different word with its own word entry in a dictionary. But that's not the case. The plural version of a particular word is applicable to all meanings listed under that single entry.

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea.- Had you included that extra information when you wrote your question, there's a good chance it would still be open.